# How do I disable or undo the launcher autohide setting?

Tags: unity, launcher, settings

I set my launcher settings to auto hide, and now I can't seem to find anything. I need to restore the default setting for the launcher. The settings menu doesnt seem to have a way to restore.

Answer (score 7):

- First press the *Windows / super* key.
- Next type *system settings* and click on system settings icon.

  [image]
- Then click on *appearance* and select the *behaviour* tab.

  [image]
- Then change *auto hide launcher* to *off*.

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-Click on the Desktop and select *Change Desktop Background*.

   [image]
2. Then Click on the *Behavior* tab in the *Appearence* window.

   [image]
3. Then click on the *Restore Default Behaviours* button.

   [image]

That's it.